# Select2 "allowClear" doesn't clear select box in some specific situation

Tags: jquery-select2

It happens when on select box change event DOM changed (some elements are shown/hidden based on select box value)
To reproduce this click select box "Clear" button in a sample. SelectBox will not be cleaned. Some select option will be set as value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selectList').select2({
     width: '100%',
     allowClear: true,
     placeholder: 'select option',
     value: null
  }).on('select2:selecting', function (e) {
    console.log('selecting');
  }).on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {
    console.log('unselecting');
  }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
    console.log('select');
  }).on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
    console.log('unselect');
  }).on('change', function (e) {
    console.log('change');    
    if(!e.value){
      $('#some-data').hide();
    }
    else{
      $('#some-data').show();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.container{
  min-width:100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #3C401D;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="some-data" class='container'>
  </div>
  <select id="selectList" name="first">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works for me:

1. Prevent open when clearing selection, as discussed here [github](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3320)
2. Open drop-down with some timeout.